# How create a serial field in a postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql update/insert are very slow. So often is faster create a new table with the new field/row and then replace the old table

The thing is I need an autonumeric so in this case I had to create the table first and do the insert later.

Is there a way create an autonumeric field in the select so I can use

```
CREATE TABLE source.road_nodes AS 
     SELECT serial_field, node
```

instead of `CREATE TABLE` + `INSERT`.

```
CREATE TABLE source.road_nodes (
    node_id serial,
    node TEXT
);

INSERT INTO source.road_nodes (node)
SELECT DISTINCT  node
FROM
   (
       SELECT DISTINCT node_begin AS node
       FROM source.vzla_rto
   ) as node_pool;
```

Comment: What if you `truncate` the table in instead of `drop`ing it?

Comment: You can reset the sequence if necessary.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Sorry the drop statment was just standard code in my side ( I remove it). The question is create a serial field in a `CREATE as SELECT` statement. Instead of create the table first as I show in my example

Comment: When using `CREATE TABLE ... AS` you should still be able to specify column types, although that appears like the wrong question to me. Why are your inserts/updates so slow? Are you using transactions to insert? Are there many stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

In a way this is possible. You can take advantage of the fact that as [the PostgreSQL documentation - 8.1.4. Serial Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) states:

> `CREATE TABLE tablename (
>       colname SERIAL
>   );`
>   is equivalent to specifying:
>
> `CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
>   CREATE TABLE tablename (
>       colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
>   );
>   ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;`

---

Creating a sequence separately and making the next value the default for the column you effectively make it a `SERIAL` column.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE road_nodes_node_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE road_nodes AS 
     SELECT DISTINCT ON (node) nextval('road_nodes_node_id_seq') AS node_id, node FROM vzla_rto;
ALTER TABLE road_nodes ALTER node_id SET NOT NULL, ALTER COLUMN node_id SET DEFAULT nextval('road_nodes_node_id_seq');
```

You could keep the sequence and just reset it to one when you would recreate the table.

**I wouldn't say that this is an elegant way however and probably the easiest way is just to create the table separately.**